# SSL Connection to Apache web server

Tags: server, apache2, connection, ssl

I follow up on setting up SSL connection to my Apache2
It works well when I access my website from a local IP address
but if I use a Dynamic DNS service with HTTPS in the beginning than
I doesn't get to the website but actually can see my website folders.

What have I done wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the port 443 in your router redirected to the host you have the server running on? If not, that could be the problem.

Try to connect to your server using the port directly:

```
https://yourpublicipaddress:443
```

If it doesn't work, you'll need to forward all the connections to the 443 port in the router to the local IP where the server is.

Comment: That was it ! I haven't forwarded port 443 on my router to the server, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Did you install any packages recently that had to do with Apache2?

If that is the case, then delete that package.

It could also be a bug.

What you might have done wrong was put HTTPS:// in the beginning instead of putting in www at the beginning.

Try that and it may work.

(Sorry, i am not a professional user.)